# Averaging over time in R

Tags: r, time, mean

I have been trying to average some data over a set time period in R and can't seem to get it to work. I adopted some code that worked to average a matrix over time just fine. However, I am trying to average relative humidity readings for every 10 minutes that were collected over a couple of weeks.

Here is the current code I was trying to use.

```
boundA <- NULL; boundB <- NULL

for (i in 1:(length(StartAve)))
{
boundA[i] <- max(which(LocalDateTime < StopAve[i]))
boundB[i] <- min(which(LocalDateTime > StartAve[i]))
}

MatMean <- NULL
MatMean <- lapply(matrix,function(z)
{
unlist(lapply(1:(length(boundB)),function(b)
{
mean(z[boundB[b]:boundA[b]],na.rm=TRUE)
}))
})
```

In this code I could read in a `.csv` file that had the start times and stop times for when I wanted the averaging to begin and end. I also would read in another file that contained a matrix and the rows would be averaged based on the start and stop times. The `LocalDateTime` corresponds to each time the data was collected for each column within the matrix (I might not have explained this well).

Like I mentioned before, the code worked for data in a matrix, but does not work now that I am trying to average data that is in a list. I was hoping someone could help me alter/create a code that would help me do this averaging.

Below is what I have

```
LocalDateTime     RH
5/24/2018 14:35   77
5/24/2018 14:37   78
5/24/2018 14:38   79
5/24/2018 14:39   78
5/24/2018 14:40   78
5/24/2018 14:41   78
5/24/2018 14:43   78
5/24/2018 14:44   78
5/24/2018 14:45   78
5/24/2018 14:46   79
5/24/2018 14:47   79
5/24/2018 14:49   79
5/24/2018 14:50   79
```

what I want returned is:

```
Avg time                     Avg RH
5/24/2018 14:30-14:40        78
5/24/2018 14:40-14:50        78.5
```

The times these scans take place are not at set intervals and has pauses occasionally so a simple code of averaging over 8 scans will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected output is a little inconsistent. Your "40-50" range averages out to either 78.375 (right-open) or 78.444 (right-closed).

Assuming this is an oversight:

```
ldt_range <- seq(
  lubridate::floor_date(min(dat$LocalDateTime), "10 minutes"),
  lubridate::ceiling_date(max(dat$LocalDateTime), "10 minutes"),
  by = 10*60
)
ldt_range
# [1] "2018-05-24 14:30:00 PDT" "2018-05-24 14:40:00 PDT"
# [3] "2018-05-24 14:50:00 PDT"
```

I'm using `ldt_range` as a set of bins. Since I use `floor` and `ceiling`, I am guaranteed to have every observation registered to at least one within `ldt_range`, though (as shown in this case) the last observation (`"14:50"`) is in a bin by itself.

```
ind <- findInterval(dat$LocalDateTime, ldt_range)
res <- aggregate(dat$RH, list(ind), mean)
res
#   Group.1      x
# 1       1 78.000
# 2       2 78.375
# 3       3 79.000
```

This is somewhat ugly, so we can get index `ldt_range` on the group number:

```
res$StartTime <- ldt_range[ res$Group.1 ]
res$Group.1 <- NULL
res
#        x           StartTime
# 1 78.000 2018-05-24 14:30:00
# 2 78.375 2018-05-24 14:40:00
# 3 79.000 2018-05-24 14:50:00
```

---

### Data

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text='
LocalDateTime     RH
"5/24/2018 14:35"   77
"5/24/2018 14:37"   78
"5/24/2018 14:38"   79
"5/24/2018 14:39"   78
"5/24/2018 14:40"   78
"5/24/2018 14:41"   78
"5/24/2018 14:43"   78
"5/24/2018 14:44"   78
"5/24/2018 14:45"   78
"5/24/2018 14:46"   79
"5/24/2018 14:47"   79
"5/24/2018 14:49"   79
"5/24/2018 14:50"   79')
dat$LocalDateTime <- as.POSIXct(dat$LocalDateTime, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```